# Using Reportlab Canvas- How to create an Option to print the pdf generated from the browser itself?

Tags: python, pdf, http-headers, reportlab

Here is the code which generates pdf for me using Reportlab.

Now, it just shows the pdf in the browser, and after including 'attachment' in the resonse.header ['Content-Disposition'], it downloads the pdf.

But what i want is the rint option which comes you in the browser, which even allows you to choose your printer. is it possible ?

```
       data = "raghav"
       p = canvas.Canvas(self.response.out)
        p.drawString(50, 700, data)


        p.showPage()

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
        self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=testpdf.pdf'
        p.save()
```

Comment: Please dont include tags in the title. Please see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to http://blog.adlibre.org/2012/04/05/automatically-print-pdf-generated-reportlab/ you can add these two lines to get the desired result:

```
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfdoc
pdfdoc.PDFCatalog.OpenAction = '<</S/JavaScript/JS(this.print\({bUI:true,bSilent:false,bShrinkToFit:true}\);)>>'
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: At least on dev-server this effects all future PDF's. If you want this specific PDF to have open action, set OpenAction on _doc.Catalog.OpenAction private attribute. Keep on mind this is meddling in internals tough

Comment: how can I use it with reportlab canvas, not worked for me.any help appreciated