# Iframe cuts at the bottom when printing in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

On IE11 printing the page below, cuts the iframe at the bottom rather than letting it expand to the next page. How can I prevent that and make it print everything?

Note: to reproduce this issue, just paste the code below into notepad and open it in IE

```
<html >
    <head>
        <style>
        .myiframe{
            width:100%;
            height:6000px;
        }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div>
            <a href="javascript:print()" ><h1>Print</h1></a>
        </div>

        <iframe class="myiframe" id="myiframe" scrolling="no" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki"/>

        <div>
            The rest of the page
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

On chrome it works fine. the content of the iframe expands and are all printed

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing Iframe in IE 11 only prints first page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735334/printing-iframe-in-ie-11-only-prints-first-page)

Comment: Just see if this helps

 https://www.appnovation.com/blog/how-avoid-your-web-printing-page-being-cut

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/973479/unable-to-print-or-view-the-print-preview-of-a-webpage-in-internet-exp

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/ie11-cant-print-web-pages/6176b43c-273f-4a00-9acc-b8f65f9c603f

Comment: 1) I see the same behaviour (as for IE) in Edge and Firefox. 2) It's not the issues that bottom is cut, it's just first page in only printed for this HTML containing `iframe`. What do you think about this?

Comment: This is really the same [question/issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965175/iframe-content-gets-cut-off-when-printing).

Comment: Can you please fix you HTML? `iframe` must have closing tag, so it should be `<iframe class="myiframe" id="myiframe" scrolling="no" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki"></iframe>`.

Comment: It is not possible  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4100079

Answer (score 9):

I tried to find some workarounds to get more or less to the same result. These solutions should work fine on any browser.

**Look at the solution 4. It seems to be the closest to what you want to achieve. (With working example)**

**Solution 1:** I think I've got a solution that is not perfect, but might do the job.

Just before printing, you replace the iframe with an image of the iframe. I found this library called `iframe2image` : https://github.com/twolfson/iframe2image.

To catch the printing event, you can use the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23170458/2525304

I haven't had the chance to test it, but I think you could get something going with this.

---

**EDIT**:

**Solution 2:**  Here is another think that could work. You could use this [Html to PDF api](http://pdfcrowd.com/html-to-pdf-api/) to first convert the content of the iframe to a pdf. Then include this pdf where the iframe was (by using [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) for example) and print the page.

Here is another api doing this: http://www.convertapi.com/web-pdf-api

---

**EDIT 2:**

**Solution 3 (working example):**
I just found [this website](https://www.web2pdfconvert.com/pdf-button) that lets you embed a `Save page to PDF` button that will return a pdf version of the page the user is on. You could replace the print button on your page with this button and tell the user to print the generated pdf.

[Working example](http://pathologist-crocodile-13111.bitballoon.com/)

The only problem is that the user is sent on another website to download the file. I think you can get a direct link to the pdf file when paying for the [basic membership](http://www.web2pdfconvert.com/membership) (5$/month).
There might be similar services offering a direct links for free that I haven't found.

---

**EDIT 3:**

**Solution 4 (with working example):**

I just found a website that gives a direct link to the generated PDF file of the page. More information here: http://pdf-ace.com/save-as-pdf-button/

[Working example](http://porter-frank-45400.bitballoon.com/) (I replaced the `Print` button)

Answer (score 7):

[image: iFrame continues through page, as you can see.]

I actually just had to add a `max-height` element and set it as `max-height: 100%;` which is what allowed the page to continue on.

You should have three existing style elements, two of which you already wrote.

They are:

```
width: 100%;
height: 6000px;
max-height: 100%;
```

Your `body` has `absolute` positioning, I assume. Try to create and adjust the CSS `height` property of the absolutely positioned element(s). Since I don't have the markup and/or CSS, I can't say what `height` needs to be set on which element(s). More than likely, it's going to be either `100%` or `auto`. Possibly even a combination of both.

When I copy and pasted the code you've provided into a file, then opened it and tried to print, I did receive the same issue. However, what I described above seemed to stretch/fix it with little to no issues.

How it's written for me currently:

```css
.myiframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6000px;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="javascript:print()">
    <h1>Print</h1>
  </a>
</div>

<iframe class="myiframe" id="myiframe" scrolling="no" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki" />

<div>
  The rest of the page
</div>
```

Comment: It's not doing it for me. So these style elements are in `myiframe` class right? are you printing using the print link and in IE11?

Comment: Yup, clicked the 'Print' redirect and also opened the form in IE11 a couple times to test it. It's strange how they differ. Are you encountering what looks to be the same type of issue, or does it appear any different than before?

Comment: It's almost the same issue except when adding `max-height: 100%` the print out if only 2 pages, one page just has the print link and the other has the iframe. where as without  `max-height: 100%`, it prints an extra empty page at the end

Comment: Padding and a lot of other things did not work. Just to be 100% sure we don't have different code some how, can you please paste all the code in your html file in the answer. thanks

Comment: @DrewFarber I am on Windows 10, I can't be not updated to latest IE11.

Comment: Hi @DrewFarber, I made a small edit to your answer. There is no need to point out edits / additions on answers. They can evolve over time. Leave comments for the comments, they shouldn't be in answers. Answers on Stackoverflow aim to provide useful solutions well into the future so craft your answers with this in mind. Stack snippets are an excellent way to provide working examples in a compact way. and on the multiple answer thing, there was no need for multiple answers because they provide one answer.

Comment: The code does not work for me either on Windows 10 (IE or Edge).