# In IE11 iframe content not print previewing to second page

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I'm working on the application the part of it renders in iframe while doing print preview by right clicking. Mozilla and Chrome show the full content and its overlaps to 2nd and 3rd page.

In IE11 its limited to one page only.

[image: IE11 print preview]

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iframe cuts at the bottom when printing in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45083085/iframe-cuts-at-the-bottom-when-printing-in-ie)

Comment: Hi Rohit, Unable to share code as it belongs to others.